# Problem with Javascript, php and Contact Form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, syntax, contacts

Hi i have some functions in JavaScript for a contact form, but Dreamweaver cs6 is showing syntax error. Can someone please help me? The first and second (let) syntax give an error as well as the final class user.

```
var fields = {};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
fields.name = document.getElementById('name');
fields.email = document.getElementById('email');
fields.message = document.getElementById('message');
})

function isNotEmpty(value) {
if (value == null || typeof value == 'undefined' ) return false;
return (value.length > 0);
}

function isEmail(email) {
let regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
return regex.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

function fieldValidation(field, validationFunction) {
if (field == null) return false;

let isFieldValid = validationFunction(field.value)
if (!isFieldValid) {
field.className = 'placeholderRed';
} else {
field.className = '';
}

return isFieldValid;
} 

function isValid() {
var valid = true;

valid &= fieldValidation(fields.name, isNotEmpty);
valid &= fieldValidation(fields.email, isNotEmpty);
valid &= fieldValidation(fields.message, isNotEmpty);
valid &= fieldValidation(fields.email, isEmail);
return valid;
}

class User {
constructor(name, email, message) {
this.name = name;
this.email = email;
this.message = message;
 }
}
```

Comment: Look at the highlighting of the post. That newline in your regex is not helping at all.

Comment: I think some character escaping might also be needed in the regex

Comment: Thank you, can you help me with an example of how i could do the character escaping please?

Comment: @BenGali  The place I originally thought might need it actually doesn't.  But the part where you do `(?:.[a-` if you expect that to match a literal `.` (dot), then you'll need to escape that like `(?:\.[a-`.  Otherwise, it will match _any_ character

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Q i have added that it still says syntax error on line 14. however if i replace let with var to create an instance of regex. it changes to next place i have used let. it seems this syntax is casuing error in cs6 only. i will test the code now with the changes you suggested.

Comment: FYI, you might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/1505169) about email address regex

Comment: Yes thank you very much @Patrick Q